# Proving the irrationality of the root of non prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

When proving the root of prime numbers such as $\sqrt 2$ (by proving how $(p/q)^2 = 2$ isn't possible for integers p and q) the proof ultimately came down to $p^2 = 2q^2$ and because 2 is a prime number p had to be a factor of 2. My question is if that is still the case when proving the irrationality of roots of nonprime numbers such as $\sqrt(27)$. Does $p^2 =27*q^2$ imply that $p=27*r$ and would this work for all nonprime numbers that aren't squares of another number?

For most proofs I saw online, people used $p=27*r$ but I don't understand why P has to be a multiple of 27. From my experimentation, I believe that $p=9*r$ would still work for the proof. Please let me know if this proof is valid or if there are any mistakes to this.

$(p/q)=\sqrt27$

$p^2/q^2=27$

$p^2=27*q^2$

$p=9*r$ (Where R is an integer)

$81*r^2=27*q^2$

$q=3*r$

Because P is a multiple of 9 and q is a multiple of 3, this contradicts the original statement that $p/q$ is a simplified rational fraction.

Comment: How do you deduce that $p=9r$?

Comment: p^2 has to be a multiple of 3^3 but since p has to be an integer p=r*3^2 is the least power you can get to satisfy the condition

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a similar approach can be used whenever $n$ is not a square of an integer.

Since $n$ is not the square of an integer there must be some prime factor that appears an odd number of times in $n$, but all prime factors of $p^2$ and $q^2$ appears an even number of times which is a contradiction to unique factorization since RHS contains that prime an odd number of times and LHS even.

Comment: Just wondering, would the assumption that p=27*r not include all the possible solutions, since there are factors of a smaller number (like 9) that make the statement true?

Answer (score 0):

Your way is correct.

But you can save a lot of time and effort when you invoke the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

- You are interested in rational roots of the equation $\boxed{x^2-n = 0}$ for natural $n$.

Now apply above mentioned theorem:

- If $x=\frac pq$ with $gcd(p,q)=1$ is a solution of $x^2-n=0$, then $q=1$ and, hence, $\boxed{p^2 = n}$. So, $n$ is a square of an integer.